# Git log first parent and follow

Tags: git

I would like get the list of merge commits related to a file + follow the file when it has been renamed. I can't find a way to achieve this despite the `--first-parent` and `--follow` flags. They can't seem to work as expected when used together.

To give you an example, let's say I have a file named `foo.txt`.

1. On the `master` branch, I append "hello" to this file and commit with the message `commit: hello`
2. I create a new branch named `branch-world`, append "world" to `foo.txt`  and commit with the message `commit: world`
3. I move to `master` and run `git merge --no-ff branch-world`
4. I create a new banch named `branch-rename`, run `git mv foo.txt bar.txt`, commit with the message `commit: rename`
5. I move to `master` and run `git merge --no-ff branch-rename`
6. I create a new dummy file `dummy.txt` without content and commit this file with the message `commit: dummy`

Given these steps:

- `git log --oneline` gives me too much information since I only want what's about `foo.txt`:

  ```
  cf0c1e4 (HEAD -> master) commit: dummy
  ca857ce Merge branch 'branch-rename'
  45ab4bc (branch-rename) commit: rename
  2057b9c Merge branch 'branch-world'
  46605f3 (branch-world) commit: world
  c52a91c commit: hello
  ```
- `git log --oneline -- bar.txt` does not provide any information about `foo.txt`:

  ```
  45ab4bc (branch-rename) commit: rename
  ```
- `git log --oneline --follow -- bar.txt` provides the children commits, rename included but doesn't show the merge commits:

  ```
  45ab4bc (branch-rename) commit: rename
  46605f3 (branch-world) commit: world
  c52a91c commit: hello
  ```
- `git log --oneline --first-parent -- bar.txt` provides the merge commits but does not retrieve the commit related to `foo.txt`:

  ```
  ca857ce Merge branch 'branch-rename'
  ```
- `git log --oneline --follow --first-parent -- bar.txt` does not return anything.

Any idea?

Comment: your last option should work; looks like bug. You could try adding -M

Comment: You were almost right! I used `-m` which tells `git` to consider merge commits as regular ones, hence solving my problem. The final command is: `git log -m --oneline --follow --first-parent -- bar.txt`

Answer (score 6):

As you noted in comments, you need:

```
git log -m --oneline --follow --first-parent -- bar.txt
```

I would argue that this *is* a bug.  The fact that `-m` gets around the problem tells us that when using `--first-parent`, Git should probably do an implied `-m`, the same way that `--follow` implies `-M` (find renames).

---

Let's start with how `git log` shows commits by default.  It begins with a [priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) into which it puts all the commits you specified on the command line:

```
git log br1 br2 br3
```

means to look at the *tip commits* of branches `br1`, `br2`, and `br3`, so those three commits (by hash ID) go into the priority queue.  If you don't specify a starting commit, `git log` uses `HEAD`.

It then plucks the next (front of queue) commit from the queue, which is the one with the highest priority.  If there's only one commit in the queue—e.g., when run with `HEAD`—that's the one commit and the queue is now empty.  The default priority is by committer-date time stamp, so that the highest-valued date—the one furthest into the future—wins this race.  If there are no future-dated commits in the queue, the one that's the least-into-the-past wins instead.  If there's just one commit—the usual case—that one commit wins the priority race.

Git now shows this commit by printing its hash ID and log message, or other details according to your `--pretty=` or `--format=` directive.  Note that `--oneline` is just shorthand for `--pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit`.

Then, ***as long as the commit is not a merge***, Git runs a `git diff <parent> <commit>` to show you the differences here.  Any diff options you add to the `git log` line, such as `--name-status`, affect this diff output.  But by default, if the commit *is* a merge, `git log` just proceeds to its last step.

Now that `git log` has shown the commit, it places all the commit's parents into the priority queue.  If the commit is ordinary (has one parent), the queue length is now the same as it was before Git showed this one commit.  If it's a *merge* commit, this puts *two or more* parents in the queue; if it's a *root* commit, it does nothing.

So, again, the overall driver of the sequence is this:

- Initialize priority queue.
- Add all command line selected commits, or `HEAD` if none.
- Loop until queue is empty:

  1. Take head of queue.
  2. Show commit hash and log message (or whatever is selected by format).
  3. If not merge, show diff.
  4. Place parents into queue.

We can change step 3 of this loop by adding any of the options `-c`, `--cc`, or `-m`.  However, we can also change the *overall* loop—steps 2 and 4 in particular—using a path name like `bar.txt`, or options like `--first-parent`, or options like `--since` and `--until`.

Really, we should restructure this loop to read:

1. Take head of queue.
2. Decide whether to show it at all.  If *selected* for showing:

   - Show commit hash and log message (or whatever is selected by format).
   - If not a merge, or if forced by `-c` or `--cc` or `-m`, show diff.
3. Place *selected* parents into queue.

Numerous `git log` options *select* particular commits, and this includes `--since`, `--until`, `--author`, `--grep`, and so on  This is true of `-- bar.txt` as well: that tells Git to select commits that *modify* the named file.

When using path names, though, `git log` turns on [History Simplification](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html#_history_simplification), which—at least by default—affects the selection in step 3 as well.  In particular, when selecting parents to put into the queue, Git does a very clever trick: it places into the queue a parent commit that *didn't* modify the file(s) you listed on the command line.  In other words, it completely prunes a side branch that *did* change the file!

If you are trying to figure out why something *didn't* change a file across a merge,<sup>1</sup> this is not what you want at all.  But if you're trying to figure out what *did* create a particular version of the file, this *is* what you want, because the merge has *ignored* the change from the branch it's *not* following.  You're trying to figure out why `bar.txt` has some particular text in it, and the branch *didn't* put that text in it in the end, so the branch must be uninteresting!

That's not what's going on in your example, but it is worth noting.  One can add `--full-history` to avoid history simplification, or various other flags to change the way the history simplification happens, but this is what all that verbiage about "TREESAME" *means*, in the documentation.

---

<sup>1</sup>In particular, if you're looking for a change you *thought* went in but doesn't seem to be in the current file, History Simplification just gets in your way, and you should use `--full-history`.

---

#### Combined diffs, `-m`, and `--first-parent`

It's now time to talk about *combined diffs*, which ties into the notion of "TREESAME".  Remember that the definition of a *merge commit* is any commit with two or more parents (usually just two).  Remember that `git diff` normally compares just *two* commits, and for ordinary commits, `git show` and `git log` compare the parent—the one-count-it-1 commit that is the parent—to the child.  For a merge commit, though, there are at least two parents.  Which one should we compare?

Git's answer to this dilemma is to use *combined diffs*, where Git compares *all* the parents to the child.  To make this easier, Git does a first pass to *eliminate* all the files where the child (merge) commit version of the file matches *any* of the parent versions.  The theory here is that since the merge's version of `bar.txt` matches at least one parent version, you don't need to see the change *now*.  Git will probably follow that parent, either because it's looking at all parents, or you're using history simplification and this is a file we care about so we're going to follow a TREESAME parent.

Hence, we will only see `bar.txt` in a *combined* diff if the merge's version of `bar.txt` is different from *every* parent's version of `bar.txt`.  In that case, Git will show the changes using the [combined diff format](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html#_combined_diff_format).

Git *does not* check for `--first-parent` here.  The combined diff code works the same with or without `--first-parent`.  This is the part that seems to me to be a bug.

Using `--first-parent` alters step 3 of our restructured loop: when adding parents to the priority queue, Git adds only the *first* parent of each merge.  Since it's only going to *follow* the first parent, it seems like this should disable the combined diff code entirely, a la the `-m` argument.

The `-m` argument tells Git to split each merge into multiple virtual children for `git diff` purposes.  Instead of making one big diff against *all* parents, it pretends that the (single) merge commit is actually multiple ordinary commits, each with one parent, but sharing the same source tree.  That way each `git diff` has just two commits: one parent, one child.

Combining `-m` with `--first-parent`, `git log` will inspect the first parent against the merge commit, which is just what we want here.

#### A side note on `--follow`

What `--follow` does is kind of a hack.  You are only allowed to give *one* path name, such as `bar.txt`, to `--follow`.  This then enables rename-finding, as if you had specified `-M` or `--find-renames`, or set `diff.renames` to `true` in your Git configuration, or [by default if you are using Git version 2.9 or newer](https://github.com/git/git/blob/90bbd502d54fe920356fa9278055dc9c9bfe9a56/Documentation/RelNotes/2.9.0.txt#L7-L9).

When Git is doing its rename finding and `--follow`ing, after deciding whether to show the commit (step 2), Git will *change* the (single) name it's looking for, if the specific target file was renamed.  In my case, after reproducing your setup, I can run this:

```
$ git log -m --oneline --follow --first-parent --name-status -- bar.txt
f2f5743 Merge branch 'branch-rename'
R100    foo.txt bar.txt
4cd490a Merge branch 'branch-world'
M       foo.txt
4afa129 commit: hello
A       foo.txt
```

The `R100` above is the result of rename detection.  Git knows that from this point onward—i.e., in commits anywhere earlier in history—the file `bar.txt` is now known instead as `foo.txt` ... so now, instead of looking for `bar.txt`, Git starts looking for `foo.txt`.

If you use `--full-history` to make Git follow both "sides" of the merge (both parents), eliminating the `--first-parent` option, we see that there is a kind of flaw here:

```
$ git log -m --oneline --follow --name-status -- bar.txt            
f2f5743 (from 4cd490a) Merge branch 'branch-rename'
R100    foo.txt bar.txt
f31ad99 (branch-rename) commit: rename
D       foo.txt
4cd490a (from 4afa129) Merge branch 'branch-world'
M       foo.txt
9b4999d (branch-world) commit: world
M       foo.txt
4afa129 commit: hello
A       foo.txt
```

Now, in `branch-rename`, we didn't actually *delete* `foo.txt`, we just don't *have* a `foo.txt` at all.  But the rename detection mechanism is being abused a bit by the `--follow` code, so that when Git goes to do the diff of commit `f31ad99` against its parent `4cd490a`, it doesn't notice that there was a rename here: it just sees that the file isn't there in the parent (and was in the child).

Fundamentally, the problem here is that `--follow` applies *at the time Git shows the merge commit:* it switch from the new name to the old name immediately.  When traversing any leg of the merge that happens to use the new name instead of the old name, it won't *see* the file there.  Only when traversing a leg of the merge that uses the old name will Git see changes to the file.

Comment: underrated comment. Thanks for your explanation.